# Laravel - Login with username, email or phone

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have implemented login with username or email in my existing project and works fine. I want to extend it to login with username, email or phone. I want a user to login with either username, email or phone number and password.

Here is my code
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Socialite;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
      public function redirectToProvider($social)
      {
          return Socialite::driver($social)->redirect();
      }

      /**
       * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
       *
       * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
       */
      public function handleProviderCallback($social)
      {
          $user = Socialite::driver($social)->user();

          // $user->token;
      }
      /**
       * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
       *
       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
       * @return array
       */
        protected function credentials(Request $request)
        {
            $field = filter_var($request->get($this->username()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
                ? $this->username()
                : 'username';

            return [
                $field => $request->get($this->username()),
                'password' => $request->password,
            ];
        }
}
```

App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:20|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required|string|max:20|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'gender' => 'required|bool',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if($data['gender'])
          {
            $avatar = 'default/avatars/male.png';
          }
        else
          {
            $avatar = 'default/avatars/female.png';
          }
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'slug' => str_slug($data['username']),
            'avatar' => $avatar,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Registration works fine and im able to store the user phone to the users table. I have changed the input type for email to text on views/auth/login.php and im able to login with either username or email.

When i change the username to phone in LoginController im unable to login with phone as it says Method [phone] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController].

When i add a method

```
/**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public function phone()
    {
      return 'phone';
    }
/**
       * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
       *
       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
       * @return array
       */
        protected function credentials(Request $request)
        {
            $field = filter_var($request->get($this->phone()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
                ? $this->phone()
                : 'phone';

            return [
                $field => $request->get($this->phone()),
                'password' => $request->password,
            ];
        }
```

It doesn't let me login with phone. Error These credentials do not match our records.
Also Tried

```
/**
       * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
       *
       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
       * @return array
       */
        protected function credentials(Request $request)
        {
            if(is_numeric($request->get('email'))){
              return ['phone'=>$request->get('email'),'password'=>$request->get('password')];
            }
            return $request->only($this->username(), 'password'); 
        }
```

I'm able to login with phone or email now but not with username
How to achieve login with username, email or phone

Comment: You are using a single field to login by using either username, email or phone correct?

Comment: @RazaMehdi Yes. That's Right! I updated the code now. I can login with either phone and email now. But looking to login with username or email or phone from a single field

Comment: You may need to use regular expressions to check whether a value is a valid email or phone. For example, for a phone you need to have exclusively numerical values etc.

Comment: @RazaMehdi i tried that and now im able to login with phone or email. But im confused how to achieve login with any of the three(phone, email, username) from a single input. Please check the updated code above

Comment: Dude i simply gave you an example. You need to establish rules as to what makes an input a valid phone number, username or password. In this case, however you may need to add your own function for authentication.

Comment: @SrikanthGopi Check out this : http://laraveldaily.com/laravel-login-email-username-one-field/

Comment: You don't need to do what @RazaMehdi is saying, that's too complex. Just attempt to login as each type. Don't worry about what was passed to you.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Showed my code on laracasts and miiikkeyyyy has corrected it in a second which works . Ill post the code

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This code works. Hope it helps someone.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
        {
          if(is_numeric($request->get('email'))){
            return ['phone'=>$request->get('email'),'password'=>$request->get('password')];
          }
          elseif (filter_var($request->get('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')];
          }
          return ['username' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')];
        }
```

If is numeric, login with number. If is email, login with email address. Else try username

Final LoginController looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Socialite;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
      public function redirectToProvider($social)
      {
          return Socialite::driver($social)->redirect();
      }

      /**
       * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
       *
       * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
       */
      public function handleProviderCallback($social)
      {
          $user = Socialite::driver($social)->user();

          // $user->token;
      }

      /**
       * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
       *
       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
       * @return array
       */
        protected function credentials(Request $request)
        {
          if(is_numeric($request->get('email'))){
            return ['phone'=>$request->get('email'),'password'=>$request->get('password')];
          }
          elseif (filter_var($request->get('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')];
          }
          return ['username' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')];
        }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, you saved me a great deal

Answer (score 17):

This code works for Laravel 7

Step 1 -- Add method username in class LoginController

```
public function username()
{
    $login = request()->input('username');

    if(is_numeric($login)){
        $field = 'phone';
    } elseif (filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $field = 'email';
    } else {
        $field = 'username';
    }

    request()->merge([$field => $login]);

    return $field;
}
```

Step 2 -- Add method sendFailedLoginResponse in class LoginController

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'username' => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
}
```

Final LoginController looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'username' => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        $login = request()->input('username');

        if(is_numeric($login)){
            $field = 'phone';
        } elseif (filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $field = 'email';
        } else {
            $field = 'username';
        }

        request()->merge([$field => $login]);

        return $field;
    }
}
```

Step 3 -- Edit view login.blade.php -> login form

- the name from name="email" to name="username"
- change error message from email to username

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username/Email/Phone') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>

                                @error('username')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: btw u dont need any other changes except for the `username()` check, and the email input type to be `text`

Answer (score 1):

To Login with `email` or `mobile` or `username`, Try this way ...

```
if(Auth::attempt(['phone' => request('phone'), 'password' => request('password')]) ||
Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')]) ||
Auth::attempt(['name' => request('name'), 'password' => request('password')])){
    // do something ...
}
```

You can add custom check fields also like "Active"='1' as: `Auth::attempt(['name' => request('name'), 'password' => request('password'), 'Active' => '1'])`

Answer (score 0):

File Address: vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {

        if (is_numeric($request->get('email'))) {
            return ['mobile' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password')];
        } elseif (filter_var($request->get('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password')];
        }

        return $request->only($request->get('email'), 'password');
    }
```