# how to change email authentication by username using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to authenticate by `username` and `password`, I modify `login.blade.php` `input` `name=email` by `name=username` , and I don't know anything else to modify in `LoginController.php`

**LoginController.php**

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/events';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    @csrf
                        
                        
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" value="FZ DIGITAL" name="username" id="inputEmail" class="form-control input_user" placeholder="username" autocomplete="username" required autofocus>
                        @error('username')
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control input_pass" autocomplete="current-password" required>
                        @error('password')
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                        <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn login_btn">Connexion</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: This [Laravel — Login with Username OR Email](https://medium.com/@shahburhan/laravel-login-with-username-or-email-ea53d61d6b3d) article might be of use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Login with username, email or phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537191/laravel-login-with-username-email-or-phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Authentication by email**

```
Auth::attempt([ 'email' => 'email@example.com', 'password' => 'password' ]);
```

**Authentication by username**

```
Auth::attempt([ 'username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password' ]);
```

**Update**

Override the trait (*Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php*) `username` method on your **LoginController.php**.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username'; // <------- Change here
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for u answer but I still don't understand where to put this code plz help ?

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: You should **never** alter code in the `vendor` folder as it will be overwritten next time you upgrade the framework. Instead you might wanna check https://dev.to/shanisingh03/how-to-login-with-username-instead-of-email-in-laravel--hj8