# Implementing multi-user login/logout using username in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-10, multi-user

I'm having trouble finding references for a program that implements a login and logout feature with multiple users using a username and password. Most references I've found use email and password for login and logout. When I try to convert the "email" code to "username", it doesn't work. Additionally, I need multi-user functionality for my project.

I tried following a tutorial video on YouTube for a multi-user login and logout system, but my page doesn't display on my monitor.

Comment: Does this answer your question (or give you hints)? [how to change email authentication by username using laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73812717/how-to-change-email-authentication-by-username-using-laravel)